# jquery mobile redirect not happening

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQueryMobile to create an ipad application. I have the following code:

```
function coursesandmodules()
            {
                var companyDBName = "abc3";
                var studentId = "2";
                $.ajax({
                       type : "GET",
                       url : "http://192.168.1.78:8087/teach/rest/student/getcoursesandmodules/" +  companyDBName + "/" + studentId ,
                       dataType : "json",
                       error: function(error) {
                       alert("ERROR");
                       },
                       success : function(data,text,xhqr) {

                       var divElement = "<div id='coursesandmodules' data-role='page'><header data-role='header'><h1>Courses and Modules</h1></header><ul data-role='listview'></ul></div>";
                       $('#loginpage').after(divElement);
                       var jsonobj = eval(data);
                       for (i in jsonobj) {
                       var stringArray =  separate(i);
                       var CTId = stringArray[0];
                       var CTName = stringArray[1];

                       var listDivider = "<li data-role='divider' data-theme='b'>" +  CTName + "</li>";
                       $('#coursesandmodules ul').append(listDivider);
                       for(j in jsonobj[i]) {
                       var myObj = JSON.stringify(jsonobj[i][j]);
                       var myJsonObj = eval('(' + myObj + ')');
                       for (h in myJsonObj) {
                       var moduleId = h;
                       var moduleName = myJsonObj[h];
                       var list = "<li><a href='#module"+ moduleId + "'>" +  moduleName + "</a></li>";
                       $('#coursesandmodules ul').append(list);
                       topics(moduleId, moduleName, companyDBName);
                       }
                       }
                       }
                       }
                       });
            }

            function topics(moduleId, moduleName, companyDBName)
            {
                var id = "module" + moduleId;
                var url = "http://192.168.1.78:8087/teach/rest/student/getmoduletopics/" +  companyDBName + "/" + moduleId;
                $.ajax({
                       type : "GET", 
                       url :  url,
                       dataType : "json",
                       error : function(error) {
                       alert("ERROR");
                       },
                       success : function(data,text,xhqr) {
                       var jsonobj = eval(data);
                       var modulePage = "<div id='" + id + "' data-role='page'><header data-role='header'><h1>" + moduleName + "</h1><a href='#coursesandmodules'>Back</a><a href='#' onclick='savemodule(" +  moduleId  + ")'>Save</a></header></div>";
                       $('#loginpage').after(modulePage);
                       for (i in jsonobj){
                       var stringArray =  separate(i);
                       var topicId = stringArray[0];
                       var topicName = stringArray[1];
                       var topicText = jsonobj[i];

                       var topicCollapsible = "<div data-role='collapsible'><h1>"  +  topicName + "</h1>" +  topicText +  "</div>";
                       $("#" +  id).append(topicCollapsible);
                       }
                       }

                       });

            }

            function separate(string) {
                var str = string.substring(1,(string.length - 1));
                var stringArray = str.split("=");
                return stringArray;
            }


            function submit() {

                var username = $("#username").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();

                var url = "http://192.168.1.78:8087/teach/rest/student/authenticate?username=" +  username + "&password="+ password;

                $.ajax({
                       type : "GET", 
                       url :  url,
                       dataType : "json",
                       error : function(error) {
                       navigator.notification.alert("Error connecting to webservice");
                       },
                       success : function(data,text,xhqr) {
                       if(data) {
                       var jsonobj = eval(data);

                       // student info
                       var currentModule = data.currentModule;
                       var studentId = data.studentId;
                       var studentUserId = data.studentUserId;
                       var companyDbName = data.companyDbName;
                       var studentName = data.studentName;
                       var userName =  data.userName;
                       var companyId = data.companyId;
                       //save data
                       $.mobile.changePage('#coursesandmodules'); 
                       }
                       else {
                       navigator.notification.alert("Incorrect username/password combination");
                       }

                       }

                       });

            }
```

When I call the coursesandmodules function in the onDeviceRead() function and submit a login form that calls the submit method, the redirect works. But right now I'm hardcoding the companyDBName and studentID values used in the coursesandmodules method. I tried calling coursesandmodules() in the submit method and passing the values from there with something like:

```
 coursesandmodules(companyDBName, studentID)
 $.mobile.changePage('#coursesandmodules');
```

And I removed the call to cursesandmodules() from the onDeviceRead() function. The redirect didnt work. It remained on the login page

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are simple point to an anchor, the docs mention nothing about this:

[docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html)

These are their examples:

```
    //transition to the "about us" page with a slideup transition
$.mobile.changePage( "about/us.html", { transition: "slideup"} );

//transition to the "search results" page, using data from a form with an id of "search"
$.mobile.changePage( "searchresults.php", {
    type: "post",
    data: $("form#search").serialize()
});

//transition to the "confirm" page with a "pop" transition without tracking it in history   
$.mobile.changePage( "../alerts/confirm.html", {
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
});
```

Comment: You can use an anchor. I have a div with an id of the named anchor and data-role='page'. With the code above the redirect works. My guess is that its not working because the coursesandmodules div hasnt been created yet. Notice some elements are being added to the dom in the first method. So when I call that method first with onDeviceReady, then submit the form, the redirect works. If I call it from submit() and remove it from onDeviveReady it doesnt work